# Save button code connecting to database not working in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, forms, save

I am trying to submit filledin information in the form to the database. I have done the below mentioned coding for the save button. When I click on the save button to save the information, I am getting an error. I need it to be done and for the same need help from the geeks around here.

COde for SAVE button data from database

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string conn = ConfigurationManager
                       .ConnectionString("welcome").ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(conn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into abhishek(pr_name,Add,add2) values(@ah,@Ap,@qe)",con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameter.Addwithvalue("@ah", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameter.Addwithvalue("@ap", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameter.Addwithvalue("@qe", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Check the error in the image below:

[image]

Comment: That's not code for the save button. That's code which runs every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an 's' from the `ConnectionStrings` indexed property. Once you fix that error, however, you will also find you are missing more 's' from the `SqlCommand.Parameters` property.

To reveal these issues, open Properties of your code-behind file, and choose Build Action of Compile.  (Also, I can see from your image that it looks like your project is setup as a Web Site rather than a Web Application; if possible, look into converting this over to a Web Application, as it offers a number of benefits.)

Once you get your syntax corrected, then you should change your code so that the update is invoked through the button click handler, rather than on page load.

In your markup code in the aspx:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

In your code-behind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["welcome"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into abhishek(pr_name,Add,add2) values(@ah,@Ap,@qe)", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ah", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ap", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qe", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note that I have moved the code into the button click event handler, and *out of* the Page_Load. The Load event handler should only be used for initialization items needed unconditionally on the execution path of the page (i.e., regardless of whatever button was clicked on the page), and should look something like the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to run every time the page is created, both initially and on postback

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        // Code to run every time the page is posted back (any submit event)
    }
    else
    {
        // Code to run on the initial creation of the page
    }
}
```

Comment: I have uploaded the error (Image) Please look at it and provide the resolution soon.